# NHibernate Tutorial Run-Time Error: HibernateException

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception, sql-server-ce, hibernateexception

I'm a newbie at NHibernate so please go easy on me if I have asked a stupid question...

I am following the tutorial for NHibernate posted [here](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/your-first-nhibernate-based-application.aspx) and am getting a run-time error of type "HibernateException"

The code in question looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using FirstSolution;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace FirstSolution.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class GenerateSchema_Fixture
    {
        [Test]
        public void Can_generate_schema()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);

            new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The line I am getting the error at is:

```
cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
```

The inner-most exception is:

```
The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly System.Data.SqlServerCe could not be found
```

And here's my stack trace:

```
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.Execute(Boolean script, Boolean export, Boolean justDrop)
   at FirstSolution.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema() in C:\Users\Kash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FirstSolution\FirstSolution\GenerateSchema_Fixture.cs:line 23
   at HibernateUnitTest.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Kash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FirstSolution\HibernateUnitTest\Form1.cs:line 23
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at HibernateUnitTest.Program.Main() in C:\Users\Kash\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FirstSolution\HibernateUnitTest\Program.cs:line 18
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I've made sure that `System.Data.SqlServerCe` has been referenced and that its `Copy Local` property is set to `True`. The error persists, however. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` to both the main project and test project? Are you testing on x86 or x64 machine?

Comment: Hi surfen, I just tried adding the reference to the test project and still get the same result. I am testing on an x64 machine.

Comment: I forgot to set the `Copy Local` property to true on the reference in the test project. It no longer crashes on that line. I will have to see if it actually works next. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I helped, I've copied my comment as answer so you can accept it after you make sure it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied as answer from comments since it turns out to be the case:

Make sure you add the reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe and set `CopyLocal=true` on **both** the main project and test project.